# Elasticsearch: aggregation of URLS

Tags: url, parameters, elasticsearch, aggregation, kibana

I want my elasticsearch / Kibana4 to give me an overview which pages of my website are viewed most. I have a field "request" but since the URLs listed there contain parameters, I get a false list of the top requests

Example:

/search?query=123

/search?query=234

Each request is shown as a single request

but

home/foobar

home/foobar

is listed with 2 requests and is the top request in this case.

How can I tell elasticsearch to aggregate the requests that contain parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to solve this.

One would be setting the url field as not_analyzed and then using script to parse out the unwanted value.

A sample script can be found here -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "urls": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "url",
        "script" : "_value.split("?")[0]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to add a [multifield](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html)  and then remove the part after '?' using custom analyzer . You can achieve this by removing anything after '?' using [pattern replace tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html)